# Use a Service-Based database in visual studio with a mobile app

Tags: c#, android, database, azure, cloud

I'm pretty new in developing pc and mobile applications that need to work with the same database.
Maybe this isn't really a question but I would be happy to get some advice from you.
I have now a vs project written in C# with a Service-Based Database. I want to create a mobile app (can be only for android) and I want both the apps to use the same database.
What options do I have? Windows Azure isn't free and I can't spend any money on this so even a small trial (limitless) will work here.
I was thinking using Parse..
What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly I would suggest you create some backend service - web service or web api - that both application use which in turn uses the database.

This will allow you to re-use business logic across both applications, abstract the database away so that you can make database and logic changes without having to redeploy the applications and avoid the requirement to deploy database credentials with your applications (the backend service should employ some form of authentication)

A free-tier [Azure mobile services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mobile-services/) can really help with the mobile device end but not necessarily on the PC (unless windows store app), but a free-tier [Azure websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/websites/) instance will happily host either web service or web api

Comment: Thanks! I'll check on that!